# Muirhead inequality doesn't require majorisation condition?

Tags: inequality, proof-explanation, contest-math, fake-proofs, majorization

I just read the proof of Muirhead Inequality [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Muirhead%27s_Inequality) and I thought it was really cool. But I do have a question, in that proof, **nowhere was the fact that ${[a_i]}_{i=1}^n$ majorizes ${[b_i]}_{i=1}^n$ used.**

> (ie. $a_i$ and $b_i$ are increasing and $$\sum_{i=1}^{k} a_i \ge \sum_{i=1}^{k} b_i \forall i \in [1,n-1] \space \text{and}\space \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i = \sum_{i=1}^{n} b_i)$$

I mean the first lemma just used that $\sum c_i = 0$ and made no mention of $$\sum_{i=1}^{k} c_i \ge 0 \ \ \ \forall \ \ \ i\in [1,n-1]$$
But surely the majorization condition is really important, right? But the proof doesn't make use of it, so I'm not sure why it is important.

So, essentially I want to know if the proof uses the majorization criteria (and if so, where) and if it doesn't, then why?

Thank you!

Comment: I think that the proof is basically incorrect. In the final expressions there shoukd be much more terms (exponents like $b_i+c_j$ should arise).

Comment: @richrow oh yes, I think you are correct, as it seems that they think that the symmetric c_i stuff is $\frac{\sum symmetric a_i} {\sum symmetric b_i}$ instead of $\sum \frac{symmetric a_i}{symmetric b_i}$

Comment: Do you know where I can find the most elementary (if it exists) Muirhead proof?

Comment: @Aditya_math https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Muirhead%27s_Inequality

Comment: @TheBestMagician that is exactly the proof we just said was wrong in the first two comments!